# Class-d Amplifier board not working after capacitor is placed in parallel at dc input while running

Tags: capacitor, amplifier, class-d

Noob here. I did a dumb thing few days ago that destroyed my TPA3110 amplifier board which is running on 24V 15A Lithium battery pack with BMS.

I placed a 35V 4700uF capacitor across the 24V output of the BMS while the amplifier is running then immediately amplifier stopped giving sound output. And also the IC is not heating up.

This question is not on fixing the amplifier but why did it stop working after this incident?

Here's the amp:

[image: TPA3110 based amplifier]

Comment: What do you mean by "placed a 35V 4700uF capacitor"? Did you connect it across an output (between L+ and L- for example), or across the battery input (between GND and VCC) or something else? Was it being fed with an audio input signal at the moment you connected the capacitor?

Comment: Oh sorry, I connected the capacitor in parallel to 24V output of the BMS.

Comment: Hopefully you just sinked the voltage rail below undervoltage lockout of the amplifier when the surge current into the capacitor caused voltage drop and/or tripped your BMS.

Comment: The BMS had no issues after that but the amplifier didn't work.

Comment: Have you tried with a different power supply?

Comment: I tried but didn't work.

Comment: Do you see if the LED lights up when the supply is applied? If it doesn't then 1) The input of the IC causes some problems so kills the supply rail, you may want to measure the supply voltage when it's applied to the board or 2) the series diode (D1) is dead (although 99.9% of the diodes go short when they are dead). Also some models have on-board FAULT LED which is tied to SD/FAULT pins. Apparently yours doesn't. You may want to check if somehow one of the outputs went short.

Comment: The led is not working and when I measured the voltage across it, its same as input voltage which shouldn't be. SD and FAULT pins are shorted in this amplifier circuit and connected to 100k ohm resistor in series to +ve. And the led has 10k ohm resistor to its led input.

Comment: And D1 diode is reducing 0.2V at its output.

Comment: What measured voltage was your "24 V" battery at? The TPA3110 is only rated to 26 V so you are dangerously close to the limit.

Comment: 22.8V now but I use a adapter which charges it only upto 24V. I used it for more than 9 months and had no problems until I placed capacitor at dc input while the amp is running